# DB2ResultSet.Read(). ERROR [24000] [IBM] CLI0115E Invalid cursor state. SQLSTATE=24000

Tags: db2, cursor

We have problem with the application run DB2ResultSet.Read(). Sometime will get ERROR :

> [24000] [IBM] CLI0115E  Invalid cursor state. SQLSTATE=24000.

Database : DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows V10.5
Client: Windows 7 64bit

Method:

```
 public int EventGetEvSegmentCnt(string SegmentID, string strEvntGroup)
            {
                int strGroupCnt = 0;
                string strSQL = string.Empty;`enter code here`
                DB2ResultSet objRs;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SegmentID) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(strEvntGroup))
                {
                    strGroupCnt = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    strSQL = " SELECT COUNT(EVNT_CODE) AS EVNT_GROUP_COUNT FROM E_SEGMENT_EVENT WHERE C_SEGMENT_ID = " + SegmentID + " AND EVNT_GROUP = " + strEvntGroup;
                    Common.DatabaseHelper helper = new Common.DatabaseHelper();
                    objRs = helper.ExecuteResultSet(strSQL);
                    if (objRs.Read())
                    {
                        strGroupCnt = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strGroupCnt = int.Parse(objRs["EVNT_GROUP_COUNT"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                return strGroupCnt;

            }
```

Error Message:

```
[Information]   System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005):

     Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [24000] [IBM] CLI0115E  Invalid cursor state. SQLSTATE=24000
       at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2DataBuffer.FetchScroll(FetchType fetchType, Int64 offset, Int32 numRows)
       at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2DataBuffer.FetchNext()
       at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2DataReader.Fetch(FetchDirection direction, Int64 offset, Boolean& isDeleted)
       at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ResultSet.Read()
```

Please help.

DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper
    {
        public DatabaseHelper()
        {
        }

        public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string commandText, List<DB2Parameter> parameters = null)
        {
            var command = GetCommand(commandText, parameters);
            var adapter = new DB2DataAdapter();

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            var ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);


            adapter.Dispose();

            return ds;
        }

        public DB2DataReader ExecuteReader(string commandText, List<DB2Parameter> parameters = null)
        {
            var command = GetCommand(commandText, parameters);
            return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }

        public DB2ResultSet ExecuteResultSet(string commandText, List<DB2Parameter> parameters = null)
        {
            var command = GetCommand(commandText, parameters);
            //DB2ResultSet result = command.ExecuteResultSet(CommandBehavior.Default, DB2CursorType.Dynamic);
            DB2ResultSet result = command.ExecuteResultSet(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection, DB2CursorType.Dynamic); 
            return result;
        }

        public DB2ResultSet ExecuteResultSetStatic(string commandText, List<DB2Parameter> parameters = null)
        {
            var command = GetCommand(commandText, parameters);
          // DB2ResultSet result = command.ExecuteResultSet(CommandBehavior.Default, DB2CursorType.Static);
            DB2ResultSet result = command.ExecuteResultSet(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection, DB2CursorType.Static);
            return result;
        }

        public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText, List<DB2Parameter> parameters = null)
        {
            var command = GetCommand(commandText, parameters);
            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Connection.Close();
            return result;
        }

        public void ExecuteSQLArray(string[] arrSQL)
        {
            var command = new DB2Command();
            command.Connection = GetConnection();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandTimeout = 600;
            command.Transaction = command.Connection.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                foreach (string strSQL in arrSQL)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSQL))
                    {
                        command.CommandText = strSQL;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                command.Transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                command.Transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            command.Connection.Close();
            command.Dispose();
        }

        public DB2Connection GetConnection()
        {
            var conn = new DB2Connection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB2_Conn"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }

        public DB2Command GetCommand(string commandText, List<DB2Parameter> parameters)
        {
            var command = new DB2Command(commandText);
            command.Connection = GetConnection();
            command.CommandTimeout = 600;

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }
            }

            return command;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I presume somewhere in `helper.ExecuteResultSet` you close the cursor.

Comment: I only call DB2Command ExecuteResultSet function.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    public int EventGetEvSegmentCnt(string SegmentID, string strEvntGroup)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SegmentID) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(strEvntGroup)) return 0;

        int strGroupCnt = 0;

        DataSet objDS=null;

        string strSQL = string.Format(" SELECT COUNT(EVNT_CODE) AS EVNT_GROUP_COUNT FROM E_SEGMENT_EVENT WHERE C_SEGMENT_ID ={0} AND EVNT_GROUP = {0}", SegmentID, strEvntGroup);

        try
        {
            Common.DatabaseHelper helper = new Common.DatabaseHelper();
            objDS = helper.ExecuteDataSet(strSQL);
            if (objRs.Table[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                strGroupCnt = int.Parse(objDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EVNT_GROUP_COUNT"].ToString());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (objDS != null) objDS.Dispose()

            return strGroupCnt;
        }
    }
```